# How can I change the default software that Android Studio opens the assets with?

Tags: android-studio

My dumb Android Studio opens the mp3 assets in text files. How can I change that setting to actually make it open with some music player?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To open the mp3 file directly from the raw or assets folder follow to below steps:

1. Select File -> Settings -> File Types -> Files Opened In Associated Applications.
2. Click on the + icon to add the format of the file
3. now add the format of the file in which you want to open.

[image]